# Rebase from one branch to another's specific commit

Tags: git, github

I want to rebase to this specific commit: `82c7b6a` in branch `master`.

This is what I am doing:

Switch to the branch develop

```
git checkout develop
```

Then do a rebase with `master`

```
git rebase master
```

But what do I add to the `git rebase` command to make it go to `82c7b6a` on `master`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just rebase off the commit:

```
git checkout develop
git rebase 82c7b6a
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do want to rebase? sound to me like you wish to do `git cherry-pick`. `git cherry-pick` is used to grab the given commit(s) into the current branch.

`git rebase` is used when you wish to re-order you history log (adding content anywhere along the history log, it can be insert into an location in your history)

---

If you still wish to use git rebase you simply need to supply the SHA-1 for the rebase

```
git rebase <SHA-1>
```